# Is blur event sufficient to validate focus out, tab out etc.?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin to validate my form. Currently I am validating the form on submit. That means any validation error will be displayed when I submit the form. Now I would like to validate each element in the form when I lose focus from the element. This way:

```
$('#txtFirstName').bind('blur', function(){
    $(this).valid();
});
```

My query is: is it sufficient to validate each element on blur event only? Will this cover any other kind of focus-losing of the element (if there exists any!)? Suggestions welcome!

Comment: `blur`  event can be unreliable in cases such as dragging some text into a text field.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, I will test case of dragging text into the textbox. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`jQuery`'s documentation](https://api.jquery.com/blur/):

> The `blur` event is sent to an element when it loses focus. [...] An element can lose focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks elsewhere on the page.

So there is no other way that could cause an element to lose focus that I can think of that is not handled by `blur()` (which is a shorthand for `.on('blur', handler)`).

AFAIK, you are good to go with this event handler.

Comment: Thank you D4V1D! For now, I will consider this safe.